# ld terminated with signal 11 segmentation fault core dumped when install aerospike from source

Tags: ld, aerospike

I am installing aerospike-server(https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-server) on centos6.3 from source,  when $make (GCC 4.7.2),  i meet this error:

```
ld terminated with signal 11 segmentation fault core dumped  
/usr/bin/ld: Dwarf Error: Invalid or unhandled Form value: 32.  
make[2]: *** [../../target/Linux-x86_64/bin/asd] Error 1.  
...
```

what should i try? can someone help me? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I used all the default tools in centos 6.3 and could build aerospike successfully from source.

The default gcc in centos 6.3 is 4.4.7. Any reason why you are using a different gcc ? Make sure you are using the correct binutils corresponding to your gcc version.

Comment: ,Thanks for your reminding. in my case, the default gcc in centos 6.3 is 4.4.6, for some reasons the gcc was upgrade to 4.7.2. maybe this cause the err. I have already installed aerospike from the RPM package . next i will install on another node by using the default gcc in centos 6.3 from source. i think it will work. than you very much!